# Using Fetch with Authorization Header and CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, authorization, fetch-api

I'm trying to get my request to go through to a online game API that I can't seem to get working. I'm using the **Fetch** API, and some request require **Authorization Bearer token**, but the request never gets sent with the authorization header.

I have tried

```
mode: 'no-cors',
credentials: 'include'
```

and obviously putting the Authorization in the header like so

```
header: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN' }
```

but the request still does not go with the authorization. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT
Heres the way I am making the request

```
fetch(URL, {
  credentials: 'include',
  header: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you actually have a token for this API?  Please show the exact request you are making, and the response that you get.  Of course, you should obscure your API key/token...

Comment: I just updated the post @MattMorgan . and I get 2 different responses based whether i use cors or not.

If i use mode: 'no-cors' then the authorization never gets sent in the header....

If i use mode: 'cors' (mode is default to 'cors') then the preflight request gets sent and responds with page not available

Comment: Can you provide the actual URL for the API, or is the URL itself private?

Comment: Its not private, but didn't think it was important. its https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2)

> Keys can be passed either via query parameter or HTTP header. Guildwars API
>   servers do not support preflighted CORS requests, so if your
>   application is running in the user's browser you'll need to use the
>   query parameter.
>
> To pass via query parameter, include "?access_token=" in your
>   request.

Answer (score 14):

The key name should be header**s**, not header.

```
fetch(URL, {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'
  }
})
```

Comment: OMG I just spent 2 hours to find out why my request is not working