# Getting 401 on API but working with postMan

Tags: fetch, es6-promise

I have this API:

```
            const url = url;
            const headers = new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json", // change to application/javascript for jsonp
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
                "access_token": accessToken,
                "id_token": idToken,
            });
            const options = {
                method: "GET",
                headers: headers,
                credentials: "same-origin",
                mode: "no-cors"
            };

            fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('-working: ',response.json());
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('-error: ',error);
            });
```

Having the same API on postMan this works like a charm there but on my code I always get 401 (Unauthorized).

Also if I remove "no-cors" I get a 401 plus CORS issue

Comment: Can you show the request details? Are you sure that the `headers` information was sent to the server?

Comment: Exactly, that was the problem. I'm sending any headers with `no-cors`. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591594/fetch-does-not-send-headers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetch() does not send headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591594/fetch-does-not-send-headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS needed to be added as an additional header on the back end

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

My senior said, that CORS is not safe, so first compare the headers of both the requests.

I would suggest you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to see the the header that is being sent from both the requests.

> Steps(step 3 and 4 is for conveniently spotting your requests):
>
> 1. Install Wireshark.
> 2. Select the network connection that you are using for the calls(for eg, select the Wifi if you are using it)
> 3. There will be many requests and responses, close extra applications.
> 4. Usually the requests are in green color, once you spot your request, copy the destination address and use the filter on top by
>      typing `ip.dst==52.187.182.185` by putting the destination address.
> 5. Tap on your request made by postman and by your call.
> 6. Compare both the headers.

In my case, I was calling the API from my react native app, and the header parameter was getting converted into lowercase automatically.
So, to correct it, I made  the parameter in lowercase in backend server.

Play "Spot the difference" between the two windows and find yours.

If this doesn't work, go with setting up CORS.