# Fetch endpoint with basic auth gives 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call an endpoint with basic auth. I made a REACT application that needs to make api calls.

This is my code:

```js
const base64 = require('base-64');
const login = base64.encode("username:password");

const fetchTemplates = async () => {
 console.log(login); // shows: dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
 const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/students/chat/templates", {
  mode: "no-cors",
  headers: new Headers({"Authorization": `Basic ${login}`})
 });
 const data = await response.json();
 if (response.status > 400) {
  console.log(data.errors);
  throw new Error(data.errors);
 }
 console.log(data);
 return data;
}

export { fetchTemplates }
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Accessing the endpoint from browser works fine with the same credentials i use in my code. Normally i should be able to see the Authorization in the request header in the console. But there is nothing.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the logs on your server, or add log statements around that request listener if they don't exist already.

Comment: This answer might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640164/2444210

Answer (score 4):

Long story short: no-cors mode restricts the kinds of headers that you can send. Authorization is not one of those headers. So you have to remove no-cors mode in order to use the Authorization header.